# GeoDjango Query Issue

Tags: python, django, geodjango

I am newbie in using geodjango, I need to check  whether a point is present in a multipolygon layer.   For trial I used

```
x = '640744.97964'
y = '2498614.18957'
p = Point(float(x), float(y), srid=32645)
pt=layer.objects.get(the_geom__contains=p)
```

but I got the error `NoneType` object has no attribute `'group'`

Answer (score 0):

Use filter instead of get, since you are not sure whether this will return 0, 1 or N layers.

```
layer.objects.filter(the_geom__contains=p)
```